# Layout of data in MC68000 RAM

Tags: assembly, ram

I am taking exam in 8 hrs...plese there are somethings i need to make sure that i uderstand properly before my MC68000 exam.

question--- Write the following values in the memory lacations below, as the microprocessor would store them as bits or hex starting at address $8000

A

2AC543 ---- for this one do i have to add two 00 in the front right?

5863a04   ------do i have to add one 0 in the front?

5D4    ------add another 0 right?

AD

BC123   -----add three 0's right?

C

F2

1B4D890378  --- not sure about this part.....

this how i did it

$8000                  0A   | 00

$8002     2A  | C5

Comment: Do you have a professor or tutor or peers that you could ask? We don't know the expected format of your exam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The m68k is big endian which means that the leftmost/first value is the highest order. So 0x2AC543 becomes

```
$8000 0x00 0x2A 0xC5 0x43
```

The interesting question for 0x5D4 is: Will it be stored as 16 or 32 bit integer? The m68k can do both, so either `0x00 0x00 0x05 0xD4` and `0x5 0xD4` could be correct.

`1B.4D89.0378` is obviously too big to store in 32 bits. If you use two long registers for it, you'll get

```
$8000 00 00 00 1B   4D 89 03 78
```

again: the highest order value comes first.

Comment: Thanks so what about 1B4D890378? how do i store that one...?

Comment: Oh thank very much...so thats means that it will only store up to 00 00 00 1B   4D 89 ? then 03 78 will not fit in

Comment: No, since 00 00 00 1B 4D 89 is too big to fit into a single CPU register. Just count the bits. When you reach 32, then the register is full. The CPU doesn't care whether a bit is 0 or 1; both count the same.